# Return an objet or id from post request

Tags: .net-core, request, return-type

Does a post request have to return a DTO like that:

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetUser), new { id = _user.Id }, _user);
```

or only the id

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetUser), new { id = _user.Id }, _user.Id);
```

Is there a guideline?